# Adding an iptables rule in %post rpm install

Tags: firewall, iptables, rpm

I've been working on packaging some software that listens on TCP ports. I have an RPM spec that creates a package for CentOS 6.5. The only issue I am having is I must manually add iptables rules or disable iptables completely after the rpm install.

Is there any idempotent way to add iptables rules in an RPM %post section. Does it even make sense? Most solutions I have found involve some combination of `grep` and other utilities. That seems extremely error prone to me.

Comment: Would [`system-config-firewall`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SystemConfig/firewall) help?

Comment: I looked at that, but it appear to be a GUI or text-ui only.

Comment: https://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/idemptables/

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS the rules are saved in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.  This file is parsed when the `/etc/init.d/iptables` script is used to start the firewall.

The problem is that this can be regenerated at any point by running `service iptables save` which means any work done by your RPM post script may / will get clobbered... same thing goes for `system-config-firewall`.

The simplest option would be to include a script with your RPM that gets run from post, that applies your rule and updates `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, and prints a warning that the script would need to be re-run if the user used `system-config-firewall` at a later date.

Example SPEC fragment:

```
%post blah
  /path/to/my/script/my-update-iptables && exit 0
```

Example script fragment:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# do stuff here
#
iptables ... # do stuff to append / insert rules as required
#
service iptables save
#
echo "WARNING - you may need to rerun this `$0` if you change the firewall" >&2
```

Comment: If you print to standard output in a `%post` section of an RPM, the package history marks the installation as being in error.

Comment: @EricUrban I don't think so. As we speak I have in-production SPEC files that have scripts that write to `stdout` and `stderr` and they work fine.  If I run `rpm --verify` no problems are reported.
  
Having the `exit 0` should be sufficient for success.  

In the example above, it is certainly possible the `my-update-iptables` script could fail in which case it should fall out of the `%post` scriptlet with error, by design...

Comment: When I had to do something like this in the past (in %post where I fixed SELinux labels under RHEL4), I put it in the %verify section as well, so if you tried to verify the install, it would re-run your script.

Comment: @AndrewMcDonnell You're installing with `rpm` most likely. I never install RPMs with `rpm`. I use `yum`.